# How to get mount --bind from Tomcat to effect the whole system?

Tags: tomcat, bind-mount

I have a folder with a file

```
/path/to/data/one/it_works.txt
```

And I have an empty folder:

```
/path/to/user/bob
```

I have a script which should be executed by a web app in Tomcat which is:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

Source="$1"
Target="$2"

/bin/mkdir "$Target"
/bin/touch "$Target/it_failed.txt"
sudo /bin/mount --bind "$Source" "$Target" || exit 1
ls "$Target"
exit 1
```

(The `exit 1` is to get the output logged by the web application. I remove it once this works.)

Sudo seems properly set up.

When I execute `sudo -u tomcat ./the-script.sh /path/to/data/one /path/to/user/bob/one` it prints `it_works.txt` as expected. If I then `cd /path/to/user/bob/one` and `ls`, I find `it_works.txt` as well. (Then, umount and rmdir $Target.) When I execute the script from the web application, I also get `it_works.txt` logged (expectable). But, if I then `cd /path/to/user/bob/one` and `ls`, I find `it_failed.txt`. Same is true for other processes (WebDAV in my case; that’s why I can’t use symlinks because WebDAV doesn’t support them).

It looks like the mount bind only applies to the process it executed it (even though `sudo`), but not to the rest of the system.

I first thought that this effect is caused by `systemd`’s sandboxing, but I set `ProtectSystem=false` and the same thing still happens...

**How can I get mount bind to effect outside the scope of the Tomcat process?**

(Distro is Debian 10.10)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior *was* caused by `systemd`, which launches services in an [`unshare`(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html) environment if *any* of the directives `InaccessiblePaths`, [`PrivateMounts`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateMounts=), `PrivateTmp`, `PrivateDevices`, `ProtectSystem`, `ProtectHome`, `ReadOnlyPaths`, or `ReadWritePaths` is enabled in the `tomcat9.service` file.

I got out of this by commenting out any of them. This is what the security part of the `[Service]` now looks like:

```
# Security
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
# PrivateTmp=yes
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
NoNewPrivileges=false
CacheDirectory=tomcat9
CacheDirectoryMode=750
# ProtectSystem=strict
# ReadWritePaths=/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/
# ReadWritePaths=/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/
# ReadWritePaths=/var/log/tomcat9/
# ReadWritePaths=/path/to/data/
# ReadWritePaths=/path/to/user/
```

(`NoNewPrivileges=false` is needed for successful `sudo`.)